# Conversion from string "SELECT patients.p_name,doctor.do" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

adp3 = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT patients.p_name,doctor.doc_name,appointments.ap_date FROM patients INNER JOIN appointments ON patients.p_id = appointments.p_id INNER doctor ON appointments.doc_id = doctor.doc_id WHERE (CONVERT(char(8), appointments.ap_date, 112) >= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) and doctor.doc_id=" + did, con)
adp3.fill(ds3)

Comment: What is the question? And could you at least try to format your code?

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding the string to a double, it tries to convert the string to a double too.

Use the `&` operator to force convesion of the double to a string, or use the `ToString` method to explicitly convert the double:

```
adp3 = New SqlDataAdapter("..." & did, con)
```

or:

```
adp3 = New SqlDataAdapter("..." + did.ToString(), con)
```